# How do I check what version of Hiera is installed on Puppet?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I tried looking this up in facter, but I couldn't find it there.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you writing modules that support multiple incompatible versions of Hiera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find out the version of Hiera and make it a fact you can use within a manifest, you can do something like this:

```
Facter.add(:hiera_version) do
  setcode do
    require 'hiera/version'
    Hiera.version.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that this code runs on the agent side. Hiera will likely not be installed there. Even if it is, its version could be different from that on the master, which is the one that will be used when compiling manifests.

Comment: Ah good point. You could turn this into a function, and functions would run on the master. Let me edit and add an example

Answer (score 1):

For looking up information on the master machine, you cannot use facts.

The [generate](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#generate) function can be used here, but it is much less convenient. I would advise to try and avoid it.